# Uneven axis in R plot

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to draw an uneven axis in R? I know that I can specify labels at specific spots, but I mean, I want a particular section of my graph to be spread out. For instance, imagine an X axis such as:

```
-10 -5 0 1 2 3 4 5 10
```

where there is equal spacing between each of the above values.

Comment: You can, but I believe you'll have to define precisely how to create this new scale, transform your data, plot it and then label the axis with the old, untransformed values. But I'd advise against it. This kind of monkeying with scales is generally considered bad practice (with the notable exception of widely known transformations like logs).

Comment: Yes, that's good advice - don't do this :)  What's the bigger picture, there might be better ways for what you are ultimately trying to do.

Comment: I know it's bad practice, but in some cases (such as mine), it is helpful. Can you show some example code

Comment: The point is: what are you trying to show?  If you just want to "zoom in" on part of the data, you're probably better off plotting two curves w/ different x-axis scales, or even 'embedding' a second plot in a window inside the main plot.

Comment: basically, i have more points between [-3,3] than in [-10,-3] and [3,10] and i want to show them better.

Comment: That's a very bad idea.  At the least, stop and think about the relative importance of the points, not just the relative quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make a factor of your levels, say "fac", and then plot. Later using axis() with labels=as.character(fac).

```
 dat <- data.frame(x=factor(c(-10 ,-5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10)), y=1:9)

 with(dat, plot(x, y))   # a step-like plot
 with(dat, plot(as.numeric(x), y, type="p", xaxt="n")) # points instead of steps
 axis(1, at=1:9, labels=as.character(dat$x))           # the "irregular" axis
```

Thinking further about @Ben Bolker's question, it should also be possible to define a an auxiliary x-value to determine the plotting "x=" and the `axis` "at=" coordinate on the horizontal and then using  `unique(as.character(.))` applied to the "real x" as the "labels=" argument to `axis` as shown above but not needing a factor construction. An even more complex scheme is possible with this approach where continuous values across specific ranges of the auxiliary variable could be used for plotting but truncated values constructed for the labels at the boundaries of those ranges. I think further design justification and specification would be needed before building an implemented example.

Comment: Would this work if there were points with x values between the breaks?

Comment: It wasn't part of the original question, and I can foresee some problems if it were desired not to have an extra "space" in the axis.